# To list all method names of HTMLElement class (or Html node object)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom

How to obtain list of all method names of `HTMLElement` class for Html node instance/object
As tried REPL on JSdom installed node js:

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v21.6.0.
Type ".help" for more information.

> const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom'); const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>')
undefined
> (node:7523) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> const document = dom.window.document
> nodeObj = document.createElement('div');
HTMLDivElement {}
>
> const methodNames = [];
undefined
> for (const key in nodeObj) {
   if (typeof nodeObj[key] === 'function' && nodeObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     methodNames.push(key);
   }
 }
undefined
>
> console.log(methodNames);
[]
```

Gave only empty array
Please help achieve it more practical, correct way

Comment: i'd look up the html dom idl - like this: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/idl-definitions.html

Comment: Why do you want to do this?